# Composer custom private package not being found

Tags: php, composer-php

I have a private-ish package repo that I'm trying to release inside the company I work for as a composer package.

I've created the package with the following `composer.json` file:

```
{
    "name": "my_team/package_name",
    "description": "Package Description",
    "homepage": "https://git.company.com/MyTeam/package_name",
    "type": "library",
    "license": "Proprietary",
    "minimum-stability": "stable",
    "version": "1.4",
    "require": {
        "php": ">=7.1.0",
        "ext-curl": "*",
        "ext-json": "*"
    },
    "autoload": {
        "psr-4": {
            "PackageNamespace\\": "src/"
        }
    }
}
```

All the paths in the package are correct, and I've created a Tag and Release on the Enterprise Github Repo that contains a zip file of the package at v1.4.

I wanted to test that the package worked, so I created a test script to run it, and it has the following `composer.json` file:

```
{
    "name": "benjam/test",
    "repositories": [
        {
            "type": "package",
            "package": {
                "name": "my_team/package_name",
                "version": "1.4",
                "dist": {
                    "type": "zip",
                    "url": "https://git.company.com/MyTeam/package_name/archive/v1.4.zip"
                }
            }
        }
    ],
    "require": {
        "my_team/package_name": "1.4"
    }
}
```

and a `main.php` file with the following contents:

```php
<?php

require __DIR__ . '/vendor/autoload.php';

$obj = new PackageNamespace\ClassName();
```

When I try to run that file, I get the following error:

```
PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught Error: Class 'PackageNamespace\ClassName' not found in C:\Development\test\main.php:5
Stack trace:
#0 {main}
  thrown in C:\Development\test\main.php on line 5

Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Class 'PackageNamespace\ClassName' not found in C:\Development\test\main.php on line 5

Error: Class 'PackageNamespace\ClassName' not found in C:\Development\test\main.php on line 5

Call Stack:
    0.2130     353200   1. {main}() C:\Development\test\main.php:0
```

So it seems that the composer autoloader doesn't see the installed package.

What have I done wrong?

Other test script `composer.json` settings I've tried are:

```
    "repositories": [
        {
            "type": "package",
            "package": {
                "name": "my_team/package_name",
                "version": "1.4",
                "source": {
                    "type": "git",
                    "url": "https://git.company.com/MyTeam/package_name",
                    "reference": "origin/master"
                }
            }
        }
    ],
```

Comment: Did you run composer update? Did it download the package successfully in the vendor folder?

Comment: Yes it did. And I ran `composer dump-autoload --optimize` for good measure.

Comment: If `composer update` was able to resolve that dependency, make sure you got what you think should have in the vendor/my_team folder.  You can also look at vendor/composer/autoload_psr4.php to see what you actually got.  Everything looks ok as far as the json files go.  Double-check for case sensitivity issues.

Comment: The zip file that it's pulling from the repo was auto-generated by Github and does _not_ have the `composer.json` file in the top level of that archive. That seems to be the cause of the issue. While it gets the package and successfully imports it, it doesn't correctly add the package data to the `autoload_psr4.php` file.

Comment: I've switched to using `"type": "vcs"` with the related changes that go along with that, and it seems to be working now.

Answer (score 0):

The issue I was having was that the zip file that was auto-generated by Github when tagging a release did *not* have the `composer.json` file in the top-level of the archive.

Because composer uses the information in that file to create the autoload settings, it was successfully importing and installing the package, but was not setting the autoload settings.

I've changed my test script `composer.json` file to the following, and it works:

(Note that there is a tag in the repo called `v1.4`)

```
{
    "name": "benjam/test",
    "repositories": [
        {
            "type": "vcs",
            "url": "git@git.company.MyTeam/package_name.git"
        }
    ],
    "require": {
        "my_team/package_name": "v1.4"
    }
}
```